# Run existing .net 4.5 app on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core

We have a big application in .Net 4.5, with WPF and a lot of references like NHibernate, Fluent NHibernate, Enterprise Library, Unity and others.

I was asked to investigate whether we can run this (after some work done) on Windows 10 IoT. As far as I know I need to port the app to Windows Universal App, and as I understood this is impossible as NHibernate won't work for Universal App.

WPF is not a problem though as we agreed we can throw frontend away if we have to.

So I wanted to ensure my understanding is correct and the only way to run our app in Windows 10 IoT is to rewrite it without NHibernate and all other 3rd party libraries that currently do not support Windows Universal App. Is this true? If no what should we do to make it work and does it require a big effort?

Comment: Do you want to put a database on the IoT device? Otherwise you should consider using a service layer (e.g. WebAPI) and keep all business logic + data access away from the IoT device.

Comment: @Bart I understand it's a proper way to do that. But our idea was to port the app in a few days. If it's not possible in a few days - we are not that interested. We can throw UI away and write another one, because it is simple enough. Rewriting database logic is much more complicated task. And we can keep DB local if it is necessary

Comment: You won't move a WPF ui to UWP in 2 days (unless it's a single screen). If you currently don't have a decent separation in layers and already an existing service layer, forget it to complete in 2 days. Rome wasn't build in a day, neither is a decent architecture/implementation.

Comment: @Bart It is a single screen. This part of app we want to move has a very simple UI but a very complex business logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a core with all the functionality in it and its separated from the front end it should be possible to use that core and then build a new front for it with UWP.

The UWP is more limited regarding access to libraries and frameworks due to it being adaptable by several platforms so might need to rewrite some platform specifik code.

So the answer depends on how coupled and platform specific the code is as it is now.

Comment: We can throw WPF away, but what do we do with NHibernate? I tried to build a small UWP app and referencing NHibernate there - it turns out NHibernate is not supported (I expected that, tried to check it anyway)

Comment: @Archeg Obviously you'd either find an alternative to NHibernate that works with UWP or you would put the database somewhere else.

Comment: @mason What do you mean by "put the database somewhere else"?

Comment: @Archeg NHibernate and it's database wouldn't be on the UWP. They'd be somewhere else, on some other platform that supports it. Your UWP would then communicate to that app.

Comment: @mason Ah, I see. I think this answers my question. We can't make it work unless put a big enough effort into it. Thanks

Comment: @Archeg Assuming you've been following good practices and isolating your data layer from your UI, it shouldn't be too difficult. That's why developers place such an emphasis on separation of concerns!

Comment: @mason We did. But I can't estimate that effort in 2 days - and I was asked about that period of time. Now is the question whether we want this bad enough to spend a week or more into it.